# Is there a shorter version of this array map arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to reduce a JSON with objects with names and other properties down to only objects with names.

At first I used this but this resulted in a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`:

```
data.map(m => {"name": m.name})
```

This works but I was wondering if there is a better way?

```
data.map(m => {
    return {"name": m.name}
})
```

Comment: Hm.  Do you need "objects with names"?  Why not just finish with an array of names?  `data.map(m => m.name);`

Comment: @James It's part of an excercise, I can't chose what the teacher wants.

Comment: @charlietfl I know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the curly brackets with parentheses, when you wish to return an object:

```
data.map(m => ({ "name": m.name }))
```

Since the names of the properties are the same, you can also use destructuring and shorthand property names:

```
data.map(({ name }) => ({ name }))
```

Comment: Still looking forward to a shorthand of the second example `data.map(({ name }) => ({ name }))` which is kinda boilerplaty especially if you have to extract multiple properties without name change.